# Using an expo module on reactNative cli project

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-cli

I'm a little new to android and React Native and would like to know if it's possible to install expo libraries in a project built on top of ReactNative Cli.
Because I will need to use some things that are not in the expo, but I would not want to lose access to the many modules it contains

EXAMPLE.:

```js
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
```

Comment: You can use expo even if you require non-expo packages. Read up on the expo dev-client, not sure what you are building but it is very likely that it can be supported with expo.